# RequestVerificationToken в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте!

- Что значит присутствие `RequestVerificationToken` в заголовке http запроса?
- Зачем  нужен еще `__RequestVerificationToken` в Cookies?
- Что тогда дает хелпер `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` в представлении c атрибутом действия контроллера `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`?

Если указать последние, то `__RequestVerificationToken` появляется еще и в данных формы. Может быть я плохо искал, но нормального объяснения не нашел.

Зачем нужно такое количество `RequestVerificationToken`?